# Correctly establishing my database tables

Tags: mysql, database

### My Initial *Flawed* Logic

Anyone who is somewhat familiar with establishing databases, creating tables and whatnot will instantly be able to see my initial logic of database establishment is completely flawed and bad practice. A somewhat snippet is below;

- Products

  - Music

    - ...
  - Books

    - ...
  - Games

    - Console_Games

      - Developers

        - ID
        - Name
        - Website
      - Manufacturers

        - ID
        - Name
        - Website
      - Publishers

        - ID
        - Name
        - Website
      - Genres
      - Platforms

        - ID
        - Platform
        - Overview
        - Developer
        - Manufacturer
        - ....

### After somewhat researching...

I'm now under an understanding that a database file root like structure is not the way forward and instead have multiple tables under the root so to speak like so;

- **Console_Games_Developers - Table**

  - ID *- int NOT NULL*
  - Name *- varchar(255)*
  - Website *- varchar(255)*
- **Console_Games_Manufacturers- Table**

  - ID *- int NOT NULL*
  - Name *- varchar(255)*
  - Website *- varchar(255)*
- **Console_Games_Publishers - Table**

  - ID *- int NOT NULL*
  - Name *- varchar(255)*
  - Website *- varchar(255)*

### Resulting SQL Query

```
CREATE TABLE User_Interests
(
        UserID int NOT NULL,
        MovieInterests TEXT,
        TVShowInterests TEXT,
        BookInterests TEXT,
        MusicInterests TEXT,
        PRIMARY KEY (UserID)
);
CREATE TABLE Game_Developers
(
        GameDevID int NOT NULL,
        Name varchar(255),
        Website varchar(255),
        PRIMARY KEY (GameDevID)
);
CREATE TABLE Game_Manufacturers
(
        GameManufactID int NOT NULL,
        Name varchar(255),
        Website varchar(255),
        PRIMARY KEY (GameManufactID)
);
CREATE TABLE Game_Publishers
(
        GamePublisherID int NOT NULL,
        Name varchar(255),
        Website varchar(255),
        PRIMARY KEY (GamePublisherID)
);
```

### The Specifics - QUESTIONS

1. How do I achieve a database like so

   - Okay so I've added what I've attempted / researched and whatnot, however I do not know whether or not this is in fact the correct way forward?
2. Am I using the correct identifiers?

   - When I use the word 'identifiers' what I mean by this is the likes of; int NOT NULL and varchar(255).

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started:

Product Type: This could be Game, Movie, Book or Music

```
create table Product_Type( id INT, description VARCHAR( 1024 ), ... )
```

Product Sub Type: This could be Console Game

```
create table Product_Sub_Type( id INT, description VARCHAR( 1024 ), product_type_id, ... )
```

Relation_Type This would be the developer or manufacturer of the product

```
create table Relation_Type( id INT, description VARCHAR( 1024 ), ... )
```

Relation: This is a prototype for a relationship like Developer, Manufacturer, etc.

```
create table Relation( id INT, description VARCHAR( 1024 ), relation_type_id INT, ... )
```

Relation_Info_type: Info types like Website, Name, Address

```
create table Relation_Info_Type( id INT, description VARCHAR( 1024 ), ... )
```

Relation_Info: This can be Name, Address or Website. (in case the relation has more than one address or website)

```
create table Relation_Info( id INT, relation_id INT, relation_info_type_id INT, description VARCHAR( 1024 ), ... )
```

Product_Relation: This would be the many-to-many way of linking relations to products, e.g. the developer and the manufacturer.

```
create table product_relation( id INT, relation_id INT, product_id INT, relation_info_type_id INT, description VARCHAR( 1024 ), ... )
```

To keep it simple (and flexible) you can do the same for Genre ( retro, action, adventure, puzzle ):
followed by many-to-many tables like

```
create table genre( id INT, description VARCHAR( 1024 ), ... )
create product_genre( id INT, product_id INT, genre_id INT, ... )
```

And for platforms ( Windows, IOS, Ubuntu, Android ):

```
create table platform( id INT, description VARCHAR( 1024 ), overview VARCHAR( 4096 ), developer_id, manufacturer_id,... )
create table platform_product( id INT, platform_id, product_id, ... )
```

These are products like the move Interstellar or the game Final Fantasy VII

```
create table Products ( id INT, description VARCHAR( 1024 ), product_sub_type_id INT, ... )
```

All [name]_id columns should be read as having a foreign key relation with table [name], except for developer_id and manufacturer_id which refer to table Relation.

Comment: In addition, I agree with what jpw said about the user_interests. Whenever you feel a need to use a plural, that basically means you want to store multiple interest instead of just one.

Comment: I'm not sure where to begin. It's not that I'm not reading your answer as I've gone through it a dozen times now trying to fully understand and grasp what you've said. I'm not sure how to link without multiple comments being here to request however would we be able to start a discussion to help clear up things a little more please?

Comment: I'd also like to share a little more on the greater outcome as this is somewhat merely a snippet therefore your answer may be correct for this question but not the correct why I should continue.

Comment: I understand it's not easy to understand an answer when it is based on something else then the real thing, but the structure I show here translates the given example. What would work is start drawing circles for each of these tables and start connecting them. It makes it easier to understand datamodelling. You see datamodeling is prototyping. When you have a horse and a cat, the prototype is animal and horse and cat are no more than childs (is-a relation) whereas paws and hooves are a particular property for that particular child class.

Comment: Say you also have a prototype with a bicycle as child, you will notice you can both ride a horse and a bicycle, regardless of the difference in prototype. So you create another class or in this case a table to join this property for both prototypes (has-a relations). This is object oriented programming 101, but it actually applies to datamodels as well, because you try to describe reality.

Comment: So treat your data the same, i.e. Find the common denominator and turn it into a prototype/parent. For instance games and books are both product types, so that is the place to store this info. Then the product can be setup with a particular type, say game, and make it a unique product by adding a description/title of the game.

Comment: Now the platforms that  are supported for this game is a one to many relation, however also a platform supports multiple games, so you have not one to many but many to many relation. That is when you create a second table that joins all valid combinations of platforms and products.

Comment: Try to read my answer again with this in mind. I think it will be easier to grasp this time.

Comment: Would you kindly add 'RaffleBananza'  on Skype? I'm still somewhat overly confused on establishing this in the correct way for my charities database. Some things do, but others I'm not so sure about. The music database I've got a dump of over 100,000,000 entries to add... I understand genres should have it's own table for normalization but not other lists...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72487/discussion-between-tim-marshall-and-avk).

Comment: It seems you are in need of a tutor, which I do not really have the time for. As a last advice please start reading www.sei.cmu.edu/reports/09tn024.pdf and continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a proper answer but turned out too long for a comment...

Without knowing your business requirements and constraints it's kind of hard to say much about the validity of the model, but remember one of the goals of the relational model is to avoid duplication of data, so think about how data is stored for a company that is both a developer. manufacturer and published of console games, while it also published  books that tie into some game franchise and the soundtracks for the games they've developed. (And maybe they do PC/Mac games too...).

The use of identifiers looks ok - it's largely a matter of style if you chose to identify a game developer as `Game_Publishers.GamePublisherID` or simply `Game_Publishers.ID`. Shouljdn't the identifying `name` attribute be `not null` though?

The `User_Interests` table looks like it could use some remodeling, but again, it's unclear what your needs are - however a column named `MovieInterests` suggests that you intend to store more than one value in it - maybe an array of interests, and if so this would break the normal form and lead to a mess and much regret later.